# Accessing redis channels available on the redis server through 'redis' package in node js

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

```
var redis = require('redis');
var redisClient = redis.createClient({host : 'localhost', port : 6379});
var x = redisClient.pubsub.channels //Cuz this is similar to PUBSUB CHANNELS
console.log(x);
```

The above code returns 'undefined' even when there are channels on my redis server. I'm I using it correctly? If so, is there any other way to access channels available on the redis server.

I'm using the '**redis**' package.

Comment: What is your expected output? Are you trying to show a list of all the channels on the redisClient?

Comment: Yes EXACTLY ! @DanielR, and is there a way to retrieve those individual channel names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `send_command` as the `PUBSUB` command isn't directly supported by the driver:

```
redisClient.send_command('PUBSUB', [ 'CHANNELS' ], function(err, channels) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Received an error:', err);
  } else {
    console.log('Channels:', channels);
  }
});
```